# Working days in month

Tags: sql, firebird

My code is:

```
SELECT 
    Sum(DR.TimeOfWork) "Skutečnost",
    SU.name "Jmeno"
FROM DevTimeRecords DR
left join SecurityUsers SU on SU.ID=DR.Worker_ID
left join DevBugs DB on DB.ID=DR.DevDocument_ID
left join DevProducts DPR on DPR.ID=DB.Product_ID
left join DevParts DPA on DPA.ID=DB.Part_ID
where
    SU.id = '@{_osoba}'
    and DPR.Code = 'ZP'
    and DPA.Code='A' 
    and not(DB.Status_ID IN ('TUPER00101','UUPER00101'))
group by
    SU.Name
order by
    SU.Name ASC
```

And I need to add column, in which will be count of workdays until today. For example: to today date this column return number 18 (27 days in month - weekends).
How can I add this column?

Comment: Will you also exclude Holidays?

Comment: people are going to ask you: what have you tried?

Comment: @BillGregg
It's not necessary, but it will be great.

Answer (score 3):

The way I handle this problem is to simply utilize a "calendar" table I created with dates out to year 2100, and a field which indicates workday true/false.

It's low tech but effective -- a plus is you can mark holidays as not a workday, and if your company decides to change their holidays you change one table instead of all the statements that compute it.

Comment: Another bonus of this approach is that if a "holiday" falls on a weekend, and either the Monday or Friday is a day off instead, you are simply updating a record.  We have a "calendar" table in our data warehouse which is also used to identify holidays in other systems.

Comment: Good idea, but at this moment I don't have any calendar.

Answer (score 0):

I recently started using recursive CTE SQL to generate data like this as needed.  The SQL below generates a calendar of data with a start date and end date.  I added an additional column to indicate the weekend days if the date is before the current_date and it is Saturday or Sunday.

```
with recursive calendar (dte,num) as (
    select CAST('1/1/2013' /* Start Date */ as date) as dte, CAST(1 as integer) as num from rdb$database
    union all
    select DATEADD(day,1,calendar.dte) as dte, calendar.num+1 as num from calendar
    where DATEADD(day,1,calendar.dte) <= '1/31/2013' /* End Date */
)
select
    calendar.*,
    EXTRACT(weekday FROM calendar.dte) as wkday,
    IIF(calendar.dte <= current_date and EXTRACT(weekday FROM calendar.dte) IN (0,6) /* Sunday & Saturday */,1,0) as wkdaytodate
from calendar
```

With some modifications you can get the a single result for that month.

```
with recursive calendar (dte,num) as (
    select CAST('1/1/2013' /* Start Date */ as date) as dte, CAST(1 as integer) as num from rdb$database
    union all
    select DATEADD(day,1,calendar.dte) as dte, calendar.num+1 as num from calendar
    where DATEADD(day,1,calendar.dte) <= '1/31/2013' /* End Date */
)
select
    MIN(calendar.dte) as dte,
    SUM(IIF(calendar.dte <= current_date and EXTRACT(weekday FROM calendar.dte) IN (0,6) /* Sunday & Saturday */,1,0)) as wkdaytodate
from calendar
```

If you need it smaller, you may simply define it as a single column.

```
select
    'test' as text,
    (
        with recursive calendar (dte,num) as (
            select CAST('1/1/2013' /* Start Date */ as date) as dte, CAST(1 as integer) as num from rdb$database
            union all
            select DATEADD(day,1,calendar.dte) as dte, calendar.num+1 as num from calendar
            where DATEADD(day,1,calendar.dte) <= '1/31/2013' /* End Date */
        )
        select
            SUM(IIF(calendar.dte <= current_date and EXTRACT(weekday FROM calendar.dte) IN (0,6) /* Sunday & Saturday */,1,0)) as wkdaytodate
        from calendar
    ) as numofweekenddays

from rdb$database
```

Others have stated that anything beyond a simple rule of "Work days are Monday-Friday" like holidays, should be stored in a calendar table and I agree with that.